# Update excel sheet cell (AO7) value in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to update the particular cell value, but getting an error. Below is the code which I tried.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook;

            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Ride\Ride Master Sheet 05 11 2020.xlsx", ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Item[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets sheets = excel.Worksheets;

            // Select worksheets
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item("Concentric Pricing");

            if (ws == null)
                return;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ws.get_Range("A7", "O7");

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row1 = worksheet.Rows[7].Cells[1, 1];

            row1.Value = "";

            excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
            excel.Application.Quit();
            excel.Quit();
```

Getting error

> Unable to cast COM object of type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type
> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'.

Any help on this?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258475/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-39microsoftoffic.html

Comment: @SotirisKoukios-Panopoulos Tried to delete and it's not allowing **(Cannot delete 1.9: Error while deleting key)**, but when we deploy it to the client. Do we need to delete it from their system too?